# how to check List<string> is null

Tags: c#

I wanna to check the values (its type is list) and if it is null, it starts again from at the beginning of the loop and if it is not, counter++. I mean if values is like: `"values": []` the compile back at the beginning of loop.

I tried with `if (id==null) and also I used this one (id.Contains(""))` but the error happens.
Error:Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index (Argument out of range exception was unhandled).

Data that I want to check (when the values is null)

```
{
  "cid": "241",
  "fnames": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "hash",
    "score",
    "rank"
  ],
  "values": [],
  "tal": 0,
  "sion": "v3"
}
```

Full data (when the values is not null)

```
{
  "cid": "64",
  "fnames": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "hash",
    "score",
    "rank"
  ],
  "values": [
    [
      "126",
      "126",
      "126",
      "1",
      "2.77"
    ],
      "tal": 0,
      "sion": "v3"
    }
```

Code

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
string url = "http://hgsfe/<uid>?groups=<uid>
var test = url.Replace("<uid>", Convert.ToString(row[uid]));
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(test);
string client = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(test);
var pi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<read_json>(client);
List<string> id = pi.values[0];
if (id==null)         //also I used this one (id.Contains(""))   
continue;
if (id.Contains(Convert.ToString(row[tid])))
{
counter++;
}
```

Comment: If a list doesn't contain any strings, it doesn't contain the empty string either. I can understand why you would initially think it does, but try to think about it a bit more, and it should become clearer.

Comment: Hmm... actually, have you made sure that `pi.values` contains any items? If that one doesn't, you cannot access `pi.values[0]` either to check whether it's empty. Also, how many elements does `row` have? Might `tid` be out of range there?

Comment: You can show more code? What is this `pi`?

Comment: let me put more code. when I only read the data that values isnot null, the code compile correctly.

Comment: pi is my data which is in JSON format @lomed

Answer (score 4):

Try checking for `pi.Count` or `pi.Length` for the number of items in the list.

Comment: Nothing change. show exactly the same error @DanielA.White.

Comment: @user3280040 which line is actually throwing the exception message?

Comment: List<string> id = pi.values[0];

Comment: then you need to guard against `pi.values`, not `id`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check both:

```
 pi == null
 pi.values[0] == null
```

because you try the assignment, but pi doesn't event exist (probably)

When you debug your code, you can clearly see, where the application crashes.

Hope i could help you with that

Comment: Neither of those checks could possibly prevent an argument out of range exception. They could prevent a null reference exception, but that's not the exception the OP is getting.

Comment: too bad =/
please add more code and maybe where the error exactly occurs (which line)

Comment: List<string> id = pi.values[0];

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
List<string> id = pi.values.ToList();
```

And after this just check the `Count` property of the list

```
if(id.Count<1)
    continue;
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you did provide code with a lot of 'unknowns', but here is what could be wrong and you should check it to make your code safer:

- what is `uid`? You are accessing `row[uid]`. `row` is of type `DataRow` where accessing item which does not exist (specified by `uid`) throws exception
- what is `pi`? what is `pi.values`? Maybe you should check if `pi` is null, `pi.values` is null and you should definately check if `pi.values` contains any items (so if item `values[0]` is present). If its empty then `values[0]` will throw exception you mentioned.
- `pi.values[0]` may be present, but it again may be assigned null. So your line `if (id.Contains...` may fail on that you are trying to call `id.Contains` on null item `id`. Check if its not null before call.
- what is `tid` in `row[tid]`? Again, check if such item is present in the row so you won't get DataRow exception.